# How can I put my Nexus 7 back to factory default ?

Tags: adb, nexus-7, factory-reset

I have a Nexus 7, that I rooted and upgraded once, but it now seems that something changed it. As it is registered in Google Play, there are way too many applications that I cannot install on it. I keep seeing statuses like "This item is not compatible with your device." while it was listed as being compatible with the tablet, as it was even analyzed in a magazine for the nexus 7.

I am ready to put it back to factory defaults, as it came out of the box. Where can I find the files to put it back ? I am familiar with CWM, and ADB.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at one of these toolkits, they each have an option for installing a stock rom back on to your device. Have included links to osx, windows and linux:

- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1837401 (mac)
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1809195 (pc)
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1848036 (linux)

Comment: Actually, I am using Linux most of the time (at least the time I can play on my tablet). I'm stuck with Windows at work.

Comment: I've added a link to a Linux toolkit :)

Answer (score 3):

Since it is a Nexus device, you don't have to root it.  Google supplies factory images for the Nexus Devices at https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images

With these images, you'll be able to reset your Nexus 7 back to factory default.